# What is the impact of setting up an index on varchar field?

Tags: sql, database, indexing

I've got a table with approx 7 million rows of data.
The schema is something like:

```
ID  - int (Primary Key)
Name - Varchar(250) Null
...
```

I want to set an index up for the Name column to speed up searches. e.g

```
Select * from table where name = 'ABC'
```

But what is the impact of setting up an Index on a varchar field?  Index size?  Does the speed benfit outweigh the cons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to search by this field often, there's no question - you need an index on it. The insertion will be a tiny bit slower, and you'll lose several MBs in your hard drive, but it's nothing compared to the look-up time you'll waive when searching for a value in this field.

Comment: A side question: Would a like search benefit from this index? e.g select * from table where name like '%abc%'

Comment: A "abc%" search will definitely benefit. Regarding "%abc%" the effect is minimal. If it's a common scenario in your application (and the tables are large or the fields are large) - you have "Full Text Search" as an alternative to simple indexing.